# How to force Sharepoint to to use Desktop version and not mobile version of a site?

Tags: sharepoint

I've installed sharepoint and i'm using it with some mobile terminals. I need to force sharepoint to 'send' ever the desktop version of site, and not mobile.
Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure it is,

You can either edit the web.config and add before the end of system.web node

```
<browserCaps>
<result type="System.Web.Mobile.MobileCapabilities, System.Web.Mobile, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
<filter>isMobileDevice=false</filter>
</browserCaps>
```

Or you can edit the compat.browser within your web application directory to specify per device if they should be understood as mobile device or not

```
<capability name="isMobileDevice" value="false" />
```

Hope it helped !

Comment: The problem about the second solutions is that i can't find my device server agent (is an old windows ce device). About the first: seems that it not ask me the authentication

Comment: You can add new entries to the compat.browser file (and be aware that this file might be cached, so you'll need to clean up the .NET 2.0 x32 / x64 temporary folders. btw, is it SP2010 or MOSS2007 ? Regarding the first one, can you clarify with "not ask me the authentication ?"